# how to solve this kind of error in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jar, jstl

i'm creating the Simple CRUD Using Jsp, Servlet and MySQL program and i'm using the eclipse, and i all most done it, finally i'm going to run myself, it can't be run. i will install the jar file of jstl, servlet, mysql connector and finally standard.jar files are installed. but i'm getting exactly this error. i will try to start the server to right click one the tomcat v6.0 server at localhost to find start button, to click and displaying this window.

**The archive: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/jtechemployee/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.**

Any one out of this problem of error, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Eclipse, open the **Server** view. Double click your server to open its **Overview** sheet. Click the **Open launch configuration** link. In the launch configuration, open the **Classpath** tab. Make sure your `classpath` is correct in that it references the appropriate libraries. Add any required libs. Note that this **Classpath** tab configures the **runtime** `classpath` for your server. Not to be confused with the `classpath` in your your project settings that is used (in this case) at compile time.

Comment: hey cmd, i ill do Open launch configuration, they Class path in here only **C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/jtechemployee/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/**, but i'm going to check the build path, in there the jar is located **C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/lib**, my seniors are already told me you must put in **C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/jtechemployee/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib**

Comment: then ill do it, copy the jstl.jar file to change that location, but i'm getting now this error: **The archive: /Simple1/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.**

Comment: Try dropping the jar into the tomcat lib dir. This may be a good sanity test as jars in that dir will be on the classpath when running tomcat

Answer (score 0):

As described by the error message itself - it sounds like the jar file you are referencing does not exist on your local system.

What do you see if you navigate to

C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/webapps/jtechemployee/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/

In your file explorer?